# Docker Compose build fails with "no such process" error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a service structure that looks like this:

```
docker-compose.yml
service/
  -Dockerfile
  -requirements.txt
  -api/
```

When I try to build the Docker image with docker-compose build --no-cache, I get the following error:

> failed to build: failed to copy files: failed to copy directory: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): open requirements.txt: no such process

I'm not sure what the problem is. Here's my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml:

## Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-buster

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /api

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

## docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  firebase:
    build: ./service
    command: sh -c "gunicorn -w 5 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 app:app"
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8088:8000"
    networks:
      - static-network

networks:
  static-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this error?

I've tried removing the requirements.txt file to see if it would build without it, but then I get the same error for every subsequent file.

Comment: On another local machine, it runs correctly. Could this be due to improperly installed Docker and Docker Compose?